# Referencing different sets of elements using d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This has to be simple, but it's been a while since I was using d3.js and I can't figure out a good solution.

I have a single set of data and I'm using it to create two sets of elements

```
 circles = svg.selectAll('.highcircles')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('circle');
```

and

```
  list.selectAll('.states-list')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('p');
```

I'd like to be able to have on mouseover of the `<p>` tags, to have the related circle animate. I can't though think of the way to link the two. Is it through a data-state attribute? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) can be used to filter down a selection based on data. You can use the datum from the `<p>` event target to filter down a `<circle>` selection like this:

```
var circleMatch = svg.selectAll(".highcircles")
    .filter(function(d) {
        return d.key === targetDatum.key;  // 'key' is some datum-unique property
    });
```

Comment: I added some more info to my answer, but I upvoted yours because I learned something new.

Comment: I agree, woodedlawn, that Scott has a good answer. I actually ended up doing it your way using CSS classes to edit the SVG values, but I might try out the .filter() function in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can add "id" attributes to your circles, and then reference those ids in your mouseover function. Something like this:

```
circles.attr("id", function(d) { return "id" + d; })

list.on('mouseover', function(d) { 
  d3.select("#id" + d)
    .style("fill", "yellow") 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/woodedlawn/7ZqZx/